# How is it possible to run Angularjs webapi at the same time as http and https?

Tags: angularjs, http, ssl, asp.net-web-api, https

I want to provide http and https support for web based angularJS project. If requested, it will work as https as well as http.

I ran the web API with https. All request and response operations are secure.

**How can project run (Web and Web API projects) both with http and https?**

Where and how do I have to manage / redirect requests that may come as http or https?

There is something that I think will help you with the question. In the configure options of Web API, only one value is allowed as project / url. (Look picture)

On the web side of the project, url and port variants can be highly improved and defined independently. So I will not have a problem there.

**RequireHttpsAttribute** ( if have to use )

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        //{
        //    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found);
        //    actionContext.Response.Content = new StringContent("<span> Http yerine artık https kullanılıyor.</span>");

        //    UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(actionContext.Request.RequestUri);

        //    uriBuilder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
        //    uriBuilder.Port = 44332;

        //    actionContext.Response.Headers.Location = uriBuilder.Uri;

        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        //}

    }
```

**WebAPI Properties**
[Project Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6H72.png)

**Web Properties**
[Project Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IlQX.png)

**config.js** (web-side)

```
//serviceBase: "http://localhost:61456/",
//servicePort: "61456",
serviceBase: "https://localhost:44332/",
servicePort: "44332"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change project property (Ctrl+W, P) 'SSL Enabled' to true. After this you will be able to request as http as well https at the same time.
[Project Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXeqv.jpg)

Comment: if ssl disabled, not work https properly. I need both of them, http and https same time.

Comment: What do you mean the same time? If you enable ssl, http continues work. Just open browser and do request by http address.

Comment: Shame on me :) Thanks captain.